# Run Chrome Built In "Capture Full Size Screenshot" through Code

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can someone please let me know if there is a code in Chrome to rung this command `(Capture Full Size Screenshot)` from JavaScript?
[image]

Comment: Use [Page.captureScreenshot](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot) as shown in the linked topic.